# Capture a string or part of a string up until a certain character

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

```
    https://stackoverflow.com | https://google.com | first text to match | 
    https://randomsite.com | https://randomurl2.com | text | https://randomsite.com | 
    https://randomsite.com | https://randomsite.com |
```

I'm trying to match the first sequence of the string which is not a url, up until `|`. In this example I would like the regex to match:

```
    https://stackoverflow.com | https://google.com | first text to match |
```

Currently I have this:

`/^(.*)[|]\s(\b\w*\b)?\s[|]/gm`

However, this only works if the first sequence which is not a url is only a string without spaces. If `first text to match` was just `first`, then it would match.

The desired result would be to match both cases, with strings without spaces and match strings with spaces.

EDIT:
Sometimes I would also need a greedy match, where the regex would match everything up until `text |`.

Comment: Personally, when I have a pattern such as this I'd rather describe/think of it as a pipe-delimited block of text, and when I do that, I'd lean towards `explode` with a URL test: https://3v4l.org/3eOUX

Comment: Php has functions for you to search for a characters location, then use that location to pull all characters up to that location. This way would not exclude any characters

Comment: I agree with @ChrisHaas . With this regex, you are simply making it complicated, unreadable and hard to debug.

Comment: Do you also need to be able to match text at the very beginning? (no leading `|`)

Comment: @Jay yes, the text at the very beginning is always a url.

Comment: Also, if you have "lines of text" and you are trying to figure out which line follows this pattern, like the answers believe it, you can also just iterate over the lines: https://3v4l.org/bcboI

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think the last example would not work in my case, because I will always just have one string. I played around a bit with your first example and I also got the desired result. Sometimes though, I need to do a greedy match, so I'm playing around with your example until it can match both cases.

Comment: @ChrisHaas this would be an example with both matches. https://3v4l.org/WSMZg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to match at least a leading url:

```
\A[\s\S]*?\b\K(?:https?://\S*\h*\|\h*)+[^\s|][^|\r\n]*\|
```

**Explanation**

- `\A` Start of string
- `[\s\S]*?` Match any character as least as possible
- `\b\K` A word boundary, then forget what is matched so far
- `(?:https?://\S*\h*\|\h*)+` Match one or more urls followed by `|` between optional spaces
- `[^\s|]` Match a non whitespace char except for a pipe
- `[^|\r\n]*` Optionally match any char except a pipe or a newline, then match the last pipe

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dIJJ32/1)

If no leading urls is also ok:

```
\A[\s\S]*?\b\K(?:https?://\S*\h*\|\h*)*[^\s|][^|\r\n]*\|
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mDLMSY/1)

Example

```
$re = '~\A[\s\S]*?\b\K(?:https?://\S*\h*\|\h*)+[^\s|][^|\r\n]*\|~';
$str = '    https://stackoverflow.com | https://google.com | first text to match | 
    https://randomsite.com | https://randomurl2.com | text | https://randomsite.com | 
    https://randomsite.com | https://randomsite.com |';

if(preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Output

```
https://stackoverflow.com | https://google.com | first text to match |
```

Comment: I like this answer - but should should have the capturing group added as well

Comment: @Urza The pattern of the OP has capture groups, but I have left them out because I assumed that there should be a match only for the whole line.

Comment: oops just re-read the original question and you're right - it does say seem to be the whole line

Comment: @Thefourthbird Neat. In this case, there will always be 2 sequences. How would this regex look like with a greedy quantifier? Then It'd have to match everything up until `text` as well.

Comment: @pu4cu In that case for a match of the 2 lines you can repeat the whole pattern for the first line preceded with matching a newline `\A([\s\S]*?\b(?:https?://\S*\h*\|\h*)+[^\s|][^|\r\n]*\|\h*)(?:\R(?1))` https://regex101.com/r/PKbhSt/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird In my example it although it looks like a newline, it's actually just one long string with spaces

Comment: @pu4cu Then you can replace the `\R` with `\s*` or `\h*` https://regex101.com/r/ZST1qi/1

Answer (score 0):

You want to include spaces

`/^(.*)[|]\s(\b(\w|\s)*\b)?\s[|]/gm`

If you want to allow all sorts of special characters in the text (**including** new lines), you can try this approach:

`\|\s*((?!\s*\w+:\/\/)[^|]+?)\s\|`

https://regex101.com/r/2OOKky/1

If you want to allow all sorts of special characters in the text (but **no** new lines), you can try this approach:

`(?:^|\|)(?:(?!$)\s)+((?!\s*\w+:\/\/)(?:(?!$)[^|])+?)(?:(?!$)\s)*\|`

https://regex101.com/r/HS3bra/1

Comment: Note that this works for the example posted, but will continue to fall over if other special chars are present in the text (eg punctuation)

Comment: @Urza Indeed, I was still crafting a more elaborate solution. I added it now :)